# How to redirect output from an infinite-loop program

Tags: linux, shell

I have a program running an infinite loop and will not terminate until receiving a `CTRL+C` signal. What I want to do is redirecting the output from this program into a file, say `log` for example. However, after I `CTRL+C`ed the program, nothing is recorded into `log`. I think it maybe some problem related to I/O buffer, but have no idea how to solve it. Am I on the right track? How to dump output from an infinite-loop program into a file?

Comment: Have you tried shrinking the buffer to zero (or the min that they will allow)? Also, do you have acces to the source code?

Comment: You could pipe the output of your program to `logger` (see `man logger`).

Comment: How are you generating the output? Simple printf?

Comment: Is this code you wrote? If so, this question belongs on [so], not on [su], though you should at least mention your programming language and preferably post some sample code that exhibits the problem. Note: do not repost, the question will be migrated automatically if enough users or a moderator push it along.

Comment: @soandos sorry, the source code is not available.

Comment: @ott-- yep. Output with `printf`.

Comment: @Gilles No, the source code is not available. I think it's something related to shell programming, doesn't know where to post the thread exactly. Thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your program is using the standard output functions (e.g. `puts`, `printf` and friends from `stdio.h` in C, `cout << …` in C++, `print` in many high-level languages), then its output is [buffered](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/): characters accumulate in a memory zone which is called a buffer; when there's too much data in the buffer, the contents of the buffer is printed (it's “flushed”) and the buffer becomes empty (ready to be filled again). If your program doesn't produce much output, it may not have filled its buffer yet.

When you kill your program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, unless you've set a signal handler for [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29), it just dies. The contents of any unflushed buffer is lost.

You have three possibilities:

- Write a signal handler for SIGINT that flushes the output buffer (`fflush(stdout)`, or `fflush(NULL)` to flush all buffers).
- Set your program to not buffer its output: call `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`. (See [C equivalent of autoflush (flush stdout after each write)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214271/c-equivalent-of-autoflush-flush-stdout-after-each-write))
- Run your program under an environment that pretends to be a terminal, so that no buffering happens. See [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000674/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Answer (score 1):

A script (with an infinite loop or not) should save the redirected data gradually, so the nature of the script should bear no result on the outcome. Data should be written in gradually ...

Or (if there is no output at all, even without redirect) you might wanna try `fflush(stdout)` or something to that effect.

Just a thought (though highly unlikely) ... are you sure redirecting `STDOUT` is what you ought to do? Isn't it by any chance `STDERR`? Try running the binary/script/... with:

`$ ./program 2> ./stderr_out`

and then `cat ./stderr_out` to make sure `STDERR`is not the one...